# Call component from onClick function in react js

Tags: reactjs, function, popup

I want to edit user details so I have

```
 <button onClick={() => this.edit(n.id)}>Edit</button>

edit = (id) => { 
     <Editbranches/>
  }
```

Here Editbranches is another component.How Can i call Component inside a user function?please Help

Comment: Call component ? Do you want to render it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to render the `Editbranches` then:

```
  <button onClick={() => this.setState({ edit: n.id })}>Edit</button>

 {
     this.state.edit && <Editbranches/> 
 }
```